# Best practice for year based paging

Tags: craft3, query

Is there a best practice for a paging based on the years of entries (instead of page numbers)?

Example:
I have 3 records with post dates 2019-01-01 2018-01-01 and 2016-01-01. So my paging should look like this:

2019 | 2018 | 2016

It is easy to fetch the needed info with a raw query like:

```
{% set pagingYears = craft.query()
    .select('DISTINCT YEAR(postDate)')
    .from('entries')
    .where({'sectionId': 1})
    .column()
%}
```

But does craft provide some components or a better way to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to craft

There is a example for a archive on the official page: [Creating an ​“Archive” Page for Entries](https://craftcms.com/guides/creating-an-archive-page-for-entries)

Maybe this fit's your use case.

Comment: Thank you, it nearly fits. The paging in the article would display every year from the first entry to now, even if there is a year without entries. So for my example above this would result in 2019 | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 instead of just 2019 | 2018 | 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Here's video tutorial series about creating date-based navigation for posts:

https://craftquest.io/courses/creating-content-archives

Keep in mind that Craft Quest is not a free site and you need purchase access to view most videos.